# Using substring with xargs in cygwin

Tags: git, bash, cygwin, substring

I'm trying to use substring functionality with on the `{}` portion of an xargs piped statement in cygwin. Here's my command without the substring:

```
git branch -r --merged master | grep "feature/" | xargs -I {} git push origin :{}
```

This is almost what I need it to do, but the command string generated by the first two parts has a "origin/" in front of it. So I just need to cut this off. I read about using `${str:n}` for substring. This is how I'm trying to use it:

```
git branch -r --merged master | grep "feature/" | xargs -I {} git push origin :${{}:7}
```

but I'm getting the "bad substitution" error message because it looks like that command needs a variable and doesn't like the `{}`. I know I could probably get around this by writing a simple bash script to iterate over the list generated by `git branch -r --merged master | grep "feature/"` but I'm guessing there's some small syntax I could change to get this working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{}` is not a shell variable. You can pass it to `bash -c` command line:

```
git branch -r --merged master | grep "feature/" | 
xargs -I {} bash -c 'git push origin ":${1#origin/}"' - {}
```

`${1#origin/}"` will remove `origin/` at the start of `$1`.